# Setting OpenAPI context on API Platform filter annotations

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I am using APi Platform with Symfony 4. I have created a range of different API Platform filters (e.g. SearchFilter, DateFilter), which I have set through annotations.

Example:

```
@ApiFilter(
    DateFilter::class,
    properties={
        "example"
    }
)
```

I want to add custom descriptions to these filters, to be displayed on the Swagger UI, for example like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX2p3.png

Is there a way of doing this through annotations or, if not, what are the simplest alternatives?

Comment: I do not think this is possible with annotations, but you can decorate api_platform.openapi.factory, see [the docs on Overriding the OpenAPI Specification](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/openapi/#overriding-the-openapi-specification)